# Angular Code Inside App-Root Tag Not Styling Correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, initialization

I am having an issue with my Angular 7 application when initializing.  I have a class called "testing", and all it does is change the text color to red.  I had the class listed in either the index.html file inside a style tag, or in the styles.scss file with all my global styles.  I tested both ways with same results.  I'm using angular/cli and ng serve to test my application and the following is how I have my index.html page laid out:

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="testing">Application is loading, please wait...</span>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

**Expectation:** The text inside the span should be red with a slight indent (via bootstrap container class).

**Actual Results:**

1. When I type localhost:4200 in the url and hit enter, the text appears to the top far left of the screen with no red color before the app gets rendered.
2. If I hit refresh the same thing as #1 happens.
3. If I hit shift+refresh, for a split second #1 happens before the text gets indented into the bootstrap container div and changes to red.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here, and what do I need to do to make #3 happen without any split second style changes?  If any additional information is needed to answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First, of all this is not right way to write even a single word in  tag because it behaves as template directive or you can say empty box to be filled by app.component.html content, and this is why you observing little flick (appears before render) and best way to write your content in app.component.html and style it through app.component.css / app.component.scss or you can write that css in main file for css (style.css) but each class should be in their component styling. Because angular is about separate modules/component/section.

Hope this helps you

Comment: The problem is that I already have content in my app.component.html template, which is the bulk of my application processing.  So the little flick will always happen there?  Are you suggesting that I create a loading status inside my app.component.html template and use that to render my loading please wait verbiage?

Comment: can you share your project folder or give GitHub repository link so i can look into